# How can I build the URL from JS file with key - url.builder not working -

Tags: magento2, javascript, url-key

I have added a Ajax function to get data, but I need to add secure key to my link.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/url',
], function ($, _, uiRegistry, select, modal, url) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        initialize: function (){

            var douar = uiRegistry.get('index = douar');

            // this.onUpdate(this.value);
            return this._super();

        },

        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {

            var douar = uiRegistry.get('index = douar');

            var linkUrl = url.build('/admin/agriculteur/lists/douar/fournisseur/' + value);

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: linkUrl,
                data: value,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                showLoader: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.douarList){
                        douar.setOptions(data.douarList);
                        console.log(data.douarList);
                        console.log('Done')
                    }else {
                        douar.hide();
                    }
                }
            });

            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: In database do you have set secure url?

Comment: i am not sure but i think that secure key is generated automatically like this : /admin/module/index/add/key/aa5e52fc035a1f54f0444b69a42581b4cd3da8d9c487e55857a0806b35b6d633/

Comment: OK, my bad, don't know why, but I thought about secure base url :facepalm:

Comment: thanks @mattkrupnik for ur interaction

Answer (score 0):

remove the last comma **mage/url,**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/url',
], function ($, _, uiRegistry, select, modal, url) {

}
```

should like this

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'uiRegistry',
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'mage/url'
    ], function ($, _, uiRegistry, select, modal, url) {
    
    }
```

URL with base URL

```
 url.setBaseUrl(window.BASE_URL);
 var linkUrl = url.build('agriculteur/lists/douar/fournisseur/' + value);
```

Comment: remove the last comma and then upgrade and then check

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I think there is another way to build url.